# How to use $and in sequalize PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, where-clause

This is my code:

```
let result = await models.trans.findAll({
            where: {
                $and: [{
                    type: 'JSON'
                },{
                    type: 'BSON' 
                }],
                language: 'English
            }
        });
```

I want to fetch data based on type, how can I pass 2 values for the same column? both json and bson type data should get return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used wrong operator. Just change `$and` to `$or`.